# sort list according to specific element with condition

Tags: python, list, sorting, conditional-statements, element

I'd like to sort a list according to a specific element in each line of the list (which is a float `@lines.split(';')[3])` but only starting from the second line. first-line has to be first-line and doesn't contain the specific element (which is an integer `@lines.split(';')[2])` :

```
list = ['a;b;c;d', 'xa;xb;3;xc', 'ya;yb;1;yc', 'za;zb;2;zc']
```

which have to give once sorted :

```
['a;b;c;d', 'ya;yb;1;yc', 'za;zb;2;zc', 'xa;xb;3;xc']
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the function in `key kwargs`.

```
l = ['a;b;c;d', 'xa;xb;3;xc', 'ya;yb;1;yc', 'za;zb;2;zc']
l  = sorted(l, key= lambda x: x.split(';')[2])
```